# HTML : doubt in textarea tag

Tags: html, textarea

when a normal HTML `<textarea>` tag is used, the size of the `<textarea>` can be altered by the user by clicking on the bottom right corner and dragging it. I notice this in many places including textareas in SO. How can I disable this resizing? Is there any way to do that?

Comment: That's something that is specific to SO, normal text areas don't have it.

Comment: This is also a feature provided by some browsers, such as Chrome or Firefox 4...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a feature provided by the browser rendering engine, not HTML itself. You can override it with CSS:

```
<textarea style="resize: none;">some text here</textarea>
```

Comment: Yes, though it'd be better to have that resize property in a style sheet rather than an inline style.

Answer (score 0):

(For Chrome) you can add some CSS to do this, as shown below:

```
textarea {
resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the resize attribute on the textarea;

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

You can also specify horizontal|vertical|both ad the value.